# Cannot Find the Top Row After Autofiltering

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have one workbook with two worksheets in it. What I am trying to do is autofilter through a range of unique values that I extracted and placed in a column in the far off reaches of both sheets. I'm then looking to copy and paste the values in the first three columns of the first visible row of what was filtered. I'm including the code below as I've tried a number of ways to approach this, but regardless of what method I use, whether to find the row number of the first row after filtering, using the code below with the `union` application, or a combination of the two what seems to happen is that when I run the filter below for "Slate Data" and then copy and paste it into the second sheet ("Placement Outlook") always results in whatever is in row 2 on "Slate Data" actual to be copy and pasted in the rows in "Placement Outlook".

The interesting and frustrating part about this is that I will get the desired result when I manually go through the autofilter and separately run the code for copying and pasting below, it's only when that code interacts with the autofilter code that it continues to only always copy and paste row 2 of the "Slate Data" worksheet into the "Placement Outlook" worksheet.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
Dim lastrowuic, lastrowarray As Long
lastrowuic = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowarray = Cells(Rows.Count, "BP").End(xlUp).Row
Dim uniquesarray As Variant
uniquesarray = Range("C2:C" & lastrowuic)
Dim sdws As Worksheet
Set sdws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Slate Data")
Dim pows As Worksheet
Set pows = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Placement Outlook")
Dim firstcell, middlecell, lastcell As Range
Set firstcell = sdws.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1)
Set middlecell = sdws.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2)
Set lastcell = sdws.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 3)
Set homeport_command_uic = Application.Union(firstcell, middlecell, lastcell)
Dim uic As Integer
uic = 2

Do While sdws.Cells(uic, 68).Value <> ""
    sdws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=sdws.Cells(uic, 68)
        If lastcell <> "" Then
        homeport_command_uic.Copy pows.Cells(uic, 2).Offset(1, 0)
        End If

uic = uic + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: For one, `Dim firstcell, middlecell, lastcell As Range` declares two variants and one range. Correct the syntax of your declarations, like, `Dim firstcell As Range, middlecell As Range, lastcell As Range`. Then move your data from the "far off places" to dedicated worksheets based on the fact that code like `CurrnetRegion` might include them and applied filters might hide rows in them. Finally, what is your purpose in applying the same filer `sdws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter` repeatedly in a loop?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is iteratively display rows that share a common value in `autofilter field:=3`. Once it filters those rows, I then want to perform some actions on those visible fields, then move on to next next value in `autofilter field:=3`, do the same actions, and so on. The first of these actions that I want to perform on these visible fields is simply copying and pasting the first three cells from one worksheet to another and that's where I'm stuck. A loop seemed to make sense, but I'm open to other suggestions. I rearranged the `Dim`s and moved the data elsewhere, but no luck yet.

Comment: At `Set FirstCell = sdWs.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).` no filter is set. Therefore what the next 3 lines return is hard to fathom. Consider just finding the row you are interested in and defining `Homeport_Command_Uic` as Union(.Cells(1), .Cells(5), .Cells(8)) or as Range(Cells(1), Cells(3)). If you want to copy these 3 cells to another location any loop, including your Do While loop, doesn't make sense.

Comment: It seems that you want to find the item in Cells(uic, "BP") in column C. VBA's `Find`` function would do that job best. Having found the row you can expand the `Found` range to include the 3 columns you want, copy and paste wherever. I wonder if you are convinced that filtering is the best way to go about this.

Comment: Your above code does exactly what you tried to do, if a filter was ALREADY applied. If you want it to do what you explained you need, you only have to insert the filtering code... You must filter A SPECIFIC RANGE, and only after that `.Cells(1, 1)` will return the address of the second row, first column of the FILLTERED RANGE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does exactly what you explain it does...

I mean, it all the time copies a range extracted only from SHEET `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

In order to  do what you need, you must refer the necessary cells to the **filtered area**.

So, you must use (if this is the range you need to filter, like I only suppose):

```
uniquesarray.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=your criteria", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

and then, set your necessary cells to be copied in this way:

```
Set firstcell = uniquesarray.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1)
Set middlecell = uniquesarray.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2)
Set lastcell = uniquesarray.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 3)
```

Setting your firstcell in the way you did, returns it with reference to the sheet range, not to the one (I understood) you need...

Do not forget to change **"your criteria"** whit your real filtering criteria!

Besides all that, it is a good habit to always put `Optin Explicit` on top of the module code, and properly declare ALL your variables. This will save you from a lot of troubles when/if the code will become bushy.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! I also fumbled around and found that after the filtered results that: 'usedrange.specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).areas(2).rows(1).columns(1)' also worked really well and was easily used with 'application.union' producing the desired result.